# How to add custom text on the bottom of QR Code image

Tags: java, zxing

zxing` lib for generating qr code inside my spring mvc application. They generate code very well , now what i want a custom text on the bottom of the qr image. 
for example---- [image]

Library i used.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code i used

```
 String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
                                Map hintMap = new HashMap();
                                hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
                                createQRCode(code,
                                        dirPath ,
                                        charset, hintMap, 200, 200);
public static void createQRCode(String qrCodeData, String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap, int qrCodeheight,
            int qrCodewidth) throws WriterException, IOException {
        BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, qrCodewidth, qrCodeheight, hintMap);
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
    }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, anyone found any solution for it???

Answer (score 0):

you can draw your text manually after you've generated barcode image:

```
var result = qrcoder.Write(inputData);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
using(var format = new StringFormat(){Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
{
    int margin = 5, textHeight = 20;

    var rect = new RectangleF(margin, result.Height - textHeight,
                              result.Width - 2 * margin, textHeight);

    g.DrawString(inputData, font, brush, rect, format);
}

result.Save(tempFileName);
```

you can select your own font size and font family which will better suite your goals.

Positioning of text is determined by rectangle you're drawing in (rect) and format.Alignment property